# Operating on strange np.array object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe in which lies a np.array of dtype=object called Fields which is causing a lot of problems. The mentioned variable can take up the following values:

```
array(['[nan]', "['3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences']", "['2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['5. Social Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '4. Agricultural Sciences'\n '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '6. Humanities']",
       "['4. Agricultural Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['6. Humanities']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '6. Humanities']",
       "['4. Agricultural Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '4. Agricultural Sciences']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '4. Agricultural Sciences']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '5. Social Sciences']",
       "['4. Agricultural Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['6. Humanities' '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['6. Humanities' '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '5. Social Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '5. Social Sciences']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology'\n '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '3. Medical and Health Sciences'\n '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['4. Agricultural Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences'\n '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['5. Social Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '6. Humanities']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '4. Agricultural Sciences']",
       "['5. Social Sciences' '4. Agricultural Sciences']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '5. Social Sciences'\n '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['6. Humanities' '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['6. Humanities' '5. Social Sciences']",
       "['5. Social Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['5. Social Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['5. Social Sciences' '6. Humanities']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences'\n '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '4. Agricultural Sciences'\n '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology' '6. Humanities']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences'\n '5. Social Sciences']",
       "['4. Agricultural Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences'\n '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology'\n '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '1. Natural Sciences'\n '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['4. Agricultural Sciences' '5. Social Sciences']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '1. Natural Sciences'\n '5. Social Sciences']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '1. Natural Sciences'\n '4. Agricultural Sciences']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '5. Social Sciences'\n '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '6. Humanities' '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['4. Agricultural Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences'\n '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '5. Social Sciences' '6. Humanities'\n '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences'\n '4. Agricultural Sciences']",
       "['6. Humanities' '4. Agricultural Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences'\n '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences'\n '5. Social Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology'\n '5. Social Sciences']",
       "['6. Humanities' '2. Engineering and Technology' '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology'\n '4. Agricultural Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences'\n '5. Social Sciences']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '6. Humanities'\n '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences' '6. Humanities']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '6. Humanities' '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '4. Agricultural Sciences'\n '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '5. Social Sciences'\n '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences'\n '2. Engineering and Technology' '4. Agricultural Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences' '6. Humanities']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '5. Social Sciences'\n '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['6. Humanities' '3. Medical and Health Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences'\n '4. Agricultural Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '6. Humanities' '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['4. Agricultural Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology'\n '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['5. Social Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences'\n '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['6. Humanities' '1. Natural Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '6. Humanities' '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['5. Social Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences'\n '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '4. Agricultural Sciences'\n '6. Humanities']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '5. Social Sciences'\n '2. Engineering and Technology' '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['6. Humanities' '3. Medical and Health Sciences'\n '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['4. Agricultural Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences'\n '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['6. Humanities' '5. Social Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['5. Social Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences'\n '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['6. Humanities' '1. Natural Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['5. Social Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology'\n '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['6. Humanities' '1. Natural Sciences' '4. Agricultural Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '4. Agricultural Sciences'\n '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['4. Agricultural Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences'\n '3. Medical and Health Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['6. Humanities' '3. Medical and Health Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences'\n '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['4. Agricultural Sciences' '5. Social Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '5. Social Sciences'\n '4. Agricultural Sciences']",
       "['4. Agricultural Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology'\n '6. Humanities']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences'\n '5. Social Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '1. Natural Sciences' '6. Humanities']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '6. Humanities'\n '2. Engineering and Technology' '5. Social Sciences'\n '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['4. Agricultural Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences'\n '2. Engineering and Technology' '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology'\n '4. Agricultural Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '5. Social Sciences'\n '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '4. Agricultural Sciences'\n '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['6. Humanities' '2. Engineering and Technology'\n '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['4. Agricultural Sciences' '6. Humanities']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences'\n '4. Agricultural Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology'\n '6. Humanities']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '1. Natural Sciences'\n '3. Medical and Health Sciences' '4. Agricultural Sciences']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '6. Humanities' '3. Medical and Health Sciences'\n '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['4. Agricultural Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences' '5. Social Sciences']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '5. Social Sciences' '6. Humanities']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '2. Engineering and Technology'\n '3. Medical and Health Sciences' '6. Humanities']",
       "['1. Natural Sciences' '4. Agricultural Sciences' '5. Social Sciences']",
       "['3. Medical and Health Sciences' '5. Social Sciences'\n '2. Engineering and Technology']",
       "['5. Social Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences' '4. Agricultural Sciences']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '3. Medical and Health Sciences'\n '1. Natural Sciences' '5. Social Sciences']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '6. Humanities'\n '3. Medical and Health Sciences' '1. Natural Sciences']",
       "['5. Social Sciences' '6. Humanities' '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['2. Engineering and Technology' '6. Humanities'\n '3. Medical and Health Sciences']",
       "['5. Social Sciences' '6. Humanities' '1. Natural Sciences']"],
      dtype=object)
```

The point is that I would like to convert those rude variables into neat strings as follows:

starting from here:

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [[1, [7,3], [1,1], "['5. Social Sciences' '6. Humanities' '1. Natural Sciences']"], [2, [1,5], [2,1], "['2. Engineering and Technology' '5. Social Sciences'\n '4. Agricultural Sciences']"], [3, [1,2,6], [2,0,2], '[nan]'],[5, [1,2], [2,0], "['1. Natural Sciences']"]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['docdb', 'cited_patents','dist_cited_patents','Fields'])
```

I would like to obtain two variables that are the same as those generated by the following code:

```
df['new_var1'] = df['Fields'].str.findall(r"'\d+\.\s*(.*?)'")
df['new_var2'] = df['new_var1'].str.join(', ')
df
```

The problem is that, while in the above mock example the code works, it does not in my original df. In my df, in particular,the '' do not appear when displaying the dictionary while they do in the mock example above.
Even when I do something as simple as: `df_analysis_df_new[~df_analysis_df_new['Fields']!='[nan]']` an error appears stating: `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'`. My guess is that my variable is of mixed type but I really need to create the equivalent of new_var1 and new_var2. How can I do that? Also I am not able to provide a sample of data because I cannot operate on such a variable basically...

Comment: quoting in the mock is not consistent.

Comment: what's the source of this data?  my guess is a csv that was written from a dataframe with array cell elements.